# How to implement the pull-down search bar in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, search, uisearchbar

In the native Calendar app, the search bar is not shown until I click the search icon and then the search bar is pulled down from top like this

[image]

If I tap the Cancel button, the search bar is pulled back to top.

I think i can mimic the effect by hiding a search bar at the top and moving it down with animation upon a button click and so on. But I wonder if there is an SDK-provided way for doing this. Thanks!